# knife cookbook upload --all returns internal server error

Tags: chef-infra, knife

When I run: `knife cookbook upload --all`

This is returned:

```
Uploading apache2      [1.6.2]
ERROR: Server returned error for https://chef.lbox.com/sandboxes/000000000000a7f169ffc8cbaefb57e7, retrying 1/5 in 3s
ERROR: Server returned error for https://chef.lbox.com/sandboxes/000000000000a7f169ffc8cbaefb57e7, retrying 2/5 in 8s
ERROR: Server returned error for https://chef.lbox.com/sandboxes/000000000000a7f169ffc8cbaefb57e7, retrying 3/5 in 16s
ERROR: Server returned error for https://chef.lbox.com/sandboxes/000000000000a7f169ffc8cbaefb57e7, retrying 4/5 in 18s
ERROR: Server returned error for https://chef.lbox.com/sandboxes/000000000000a7f169ffc8cbaefb57e7, retrying 5/5 in 53s
ERROR: internal server error
Response: internal service error
```

I checked the server logs with `chef-server-ctl tail`

And the logs are crazy. http://pastebin.com/ee9fR90j

Any suggestions on why I can't upload cookbooks? Where can I go to see more detailed errors? I'm at a loss. Thank you.

Comment: This was a bug in Chef - [CHEF-4504](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4504) and has since been resolved upstream.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is [CHEF-4504](https://tickets.opscode.com/browse/CHEF-4504)?

> I workaround this issue by setting `--concurrency 1` while cookbooks upload.

The issue mentioned there has been resolved in the mean time (but as today not released, yet).

> Any nightly later than chef-server-11.0.8+20130905085844.git.41.06d37db will contain the fix.